# Howto fix a broken/interrupted Bus line?

Tags: cities-xl, cities-xxl

I have placed a Bus terminal and a route through my city.
 
Unfortunatley, this line is 'broken'/'interrupted' at some point.

How can I fix such a broken line?
I can't find a possibility to 'extend' the existing line or 'add' the missing piece.

*I'm not sure about this:

Does a broken Bus line work at all?*

Answer (score 1):

To verify if a bus line works even if it has been interrupted, you can take a look at the bus line pannel accessible from the top menu. If there are passengers, then the line is working.

And for the way to fix it, there may be better solutions but I think I would just delete the line and re-create it.

*This is all not tested because my game is not currently installed.*

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
click on the bus line
then you will see the line (that flashes black) 
find part of the line that is broken(I mean a part of the line is disconnected from the other part and your bus line is like a open rope! not a complete circle)
then recreate the road that the broken part was going through that road(I mean the road that your broken PART was there)
and everything will be ok!
if you see that it's broken again
do it more times and try another roads that was a part of your bus line(that is broken now)

Answer (score 0):

If you organized the bus line when the game paused, you can recieve this masage. Try to continue the game to make the line active.

Answer (score -1):

I have just started to have a "blueprint" project and I saw that my bus lines are broken.
I guess "blueprint" project is the cause of this broken lines

Comment: So how do you fix it? That's what was being asked.